# "Raspberry Pi Zero W" version Help

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w

Can anyone help me about **"Raspberry pi zero w" version 1.1**?

I recently ordered my first Raspberry **Pi Zero W (1.3)**, But I got **Pi Zero W (1.1)**.
There are many difference between them...

But I know that **v1.3 has camera pad on board**... and **Printed "Camera" beside it**...

But, there is **Same pad on v1.1 also**...!! But There is **no any Printed title** there...

**If the version 1.1 has no camera pad, then which pad it is on v1.1?**

[image]

(I am gonna replace it, but if they don't had stock of v1.3, then I've to just return it)

What should I do... Please help, If anyone really know about those various version of "pi-zero-w"...

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pi Zero W v1.1 does come with the 15-pin MIPI camera interface (CSI) connector - it is just not labelled as it is on the Pi Zero v1.3. Notice that this is the Pi Zero without WiFi, thus there is no "W" in the type. Obviously the additional WiFi components required moving the components of the voltage regulator closer to the connector thus occupying the space otherwise used for the print.

According to the [table of generations of the Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications) the Zero up to (and including) board revision v1.2 is missing the CSI connector, while the Zero v1.3 and the Zero W (all known board revisions) provide it (again, mind the difference of "W" - WiFi or not).

This figure (source: [Sparkfun](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/6/7/6/PiZero_1.pdf)) has sorted it out quite nicely for the Zero W v1.1 and the Zero v1.3:

[image]

The image linked in the question shows clearly a Zero W as there is the WiFi circuitry and the on-board antenna (the "triangular" area) next the the "data"-micro USB port.

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much... I didn't notice that, one of the image is of "pi zero"... So I confused... Also I just talked to the technician, they just said "pi zero w" supports camera on any version... Thanks a lot...

Comment: so their is no way to add picamera to pi zero ver 1.1 ?